# Best way to do user group with posts in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a developer that just started with Rails and i have built a couple of more simple applications. However, do i have an idea for a project that requires me to build a webapp that have users and "user groups" with posts.

The users should be able to join a group and then post posts into the group. On top of this i also want users to be able to see the latest posts in the groups they are a part of in a "dashboard" "flow" (like the facebook flow). What i am wondering is how the relationships should be like in this scenario?

I have read that has_many_through is a good way to build users that belongs to groups, but how should i make the relationships so that the groups have posts as well?

Comment: I think you should narrow you question as it's likely to get closed because it's too broad in this form. You probably should narrow it to something like "how should the relationships be like" with showing what you have in mind in a more clear way.

Comment: Ok, i will try to make it more clear that i am asking about how the relationships should be built

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good way in my opinion:

```
def User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :groups, through: :membership
    has_many :posts
end

def Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :user
    belongs_to :group
end

def Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users, through: :membership
    has_many :posts
end

def Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user is creating the posts, it would make sense to have the posts belong to the user. But the user is posting in a group, so the posts can also belong to a group.

Therefore, each user `has_many` posts and each group `has_many` posts as well.

To link users and groups initially (through a join table), you can use the `has_many_and_belongs_to` relationship.

## The Migrations

#### Users

Run `rails g model User name:string` to produce the migration:

```
#create_users
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :users do |t|
            t.string :name
            <other fields...>
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
 end
```

and a basic model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

#### Groups

Run `rails g model Group name:string` to produce the migration:

```
#create_groups
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :groups do |t|
            t.string :name
            <other fields...>
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
 end
```

and a basic model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

#### Join Table

To link users and groups initially (a membership table)...

Run `rails g migration CreateJoinTableUserGroup user group` to produce:

```
class CreateJoinTableUserGroup < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_join_table :users, :groups
    end
end
```

#### Posts

And go ahead and create a `posts` table: `rails g migration CreatePosts`. And change the migration to look like:

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :posts do |t|
            t.string :text
            t.belongs_to :user
            t.belongs_to :group

            <other fields...>
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
 end
```

At this point, you would want to run `rake db:migrate`.

## The Models

Here's what I would do for models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    has_and_belongs_to_many :groups, :join_table => :groups_users
end
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :groups_users
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :group
end
```

Hope that helps!